# How to get buttons to be inline with box

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys I'm trying to create a simple quantity box, so that the user can decide how much quantity they want.

E.G:

[image]

However my buttons are on the top and bottom of the box so it goes:

```
- 
Box 
+
```

I tried to use `display: inline; / inline block` but no luck , any help would be great, I'm using bootstrap 3.

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group plus-minus-input">
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <button type="button" class="button hollow circle" data-quantity="minus" data-field="quantity">
      <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <input class="input-group-field" type="number" name="quantity" value="0">
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <button type="button" class="button hollow circle" data-quantity="plus" data-field="quantity">
      <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.plus-minus-input {
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.plus-minus-input .input-group-field {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.plus-minus-input .input-group-field::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.plus-minus-input .input-group-field ::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
}

.plus-minus-input .input-group-button .circle {

  padding: 0.25em 0.8em;
}
```

Comment: How did you try selecting the children to apply display: inline-block? This should work: `.input-group > * { display: inline-block; }`

Comment: which version of bootstrap have you used..?

Comment: Try `float:left` property to align.

Comment: Just use [button add-ons](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups-buttons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change You css like this**

```
.plus-minus-input {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.plus-minus-input .input-group-field {
    text-align: center;
    padding: .62em;
}
 .plus-minus-input .input-group-field::-webkit-inner-spin-button, .plus-minus-input .input-group-field ::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
.plus-minus-input .input-group-button .circle {
    padding: 1.25em 1.8em;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Bootstrap, you can add d-flex to your parent div like `<div class="input-group plus-minus-input d-flex">`

Comment: The `.d-flex` is defined in Bootstrap since version 4, while OP uses Bootstrap 3.